# Change Charset Response Header for Apache Indexes

Tags: apache, utf-8, character-encoding, indexing

I'm trying to set up [windex](https://github.com/desandro/windex) on my local apache server for changing the auto-generated file indexes; some of my files and folders have utf-8 characters such as ».

This shouldn't be a problem, as the html header has the charset set to `utf-8`. The php files have been encoded in `utf-8`. I've even set '`AddDefaultCharset`' to off in my httpd.conf for the Apache server, but when I try to load any page, I get '`Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1`' in the response header.

What is causing this, and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out that Apache has a separate setting for encoding the indexes it generates. You can set the charset for an index by adding this line to an `.htaccess` file, placed in the directory where your index will be generated:

```
IndexOptions Charset=UTF-8
```

This fixed it for me!

Comment: Thank you, this gave me the hint I needed to figure this out!
I ran into the same problem when migrating a server from apache 2.2 on CentOS 6 to 2.4 on CentOs 7.
The old server had `IndexOptions Charset=UTF-8` in its `httpd.conf` (I guess by default?).
A fresh apache 2.4 on CentOs 7 was missing the charset-option in `conf.d/autoindex.conf`. Fixed now that I've added it!

Answer (score 2):

[AddDefaultCharset](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset) is used when a response header's content-type is text/plain or text/html
In .htaccess or httpd.conf you can add:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

[AddCharset](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addcharset) is to define the character set for any given file extension.

In .htaccess or httpd.conf you can add:

```
AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .php .txt .js
```

In PHP (before any page content is output):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

If you *HAVE*  to use the HTML meta tag (cannot edit config or htaccess) it must be the first thing that follows the `<head>`
Reference: [Best Practice: Get your HEAD in order](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/18/optimal-html-head-ordering-to-avoid-parser-restarts-redownloads-and-improve-performance.aspx)

```
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```